# How to prevent WP from inserting empty posts

Tags: posts

I am writing a plugin that has a custom post type that uses mostly custom fields. I disabled nearly every feature of my CPT so I can make sure the fields follow certain guidelines. If all of the fields dont follow all of the rules when the form is submitted, none of the meta will be updated. When this happens, WP still inserts the post with barely any data in it. I want to stop WP from inserting an empty post. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Due to auto-save's the post will always exist in WordPress, it's inserted into the database as soon as content is entered. So you can't prevent an entry, - however you can filter after a user hits "Publish" or "Save" on the post using [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post), or [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). With this action you can do your conditional checking and change the post_status from publish to draft, or whatever is needed for your plugin.

For example:

```
function _myplugin_save_post_check($post_id) {
    // If this is a revision, get real post ID
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
        $post_id = $parent_id;

    // Do whatever conditional checks you want here, like checking the custom feilds values
    $custom_feilds = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'whatever', true );

    if ( empty( $custom_feilds ) ) {
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', '_myplugin_save_post_check' );

        // update the post as unpublished, or whatever
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft' ) );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', '_myplugin_save_post_check' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', '_myplugin_save_post_check' );
```

The above will make the post a draft if the custom meta field `'whatever'` is empty.